# Does almost sure ordering, same distributional convergence imply convergence in probability?

Tags: probability, weak-convergence

Suppose $X_n$, $Y_n$ are real valued random variables such that $X_n \leq Y_n$ a.s. If $X_n \xrightarrow{d} X$,  and $Y_n \xrightarrow{d} X$ can I say that $Y_n-X_n\xrightarrow{P}0$?

Comment: No! Try to make an example ...